# PDO login error doesnt match result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello i have a script for login and i'm using SHA512 for encryping pass. The thing is my script somehow doesnt fetch info with database table and i dont know why. My script returns "error_msg". Here is my code

```
<?php

session_start();
include ('engine/core/dbconfig.php');   
$password=$_POST['password'];
$username=$_POST['username'];

if ($password='' or $username='') {
    echo 'mandatory';
} else {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Admin_Local where Username=:username and Password=:hashed"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hashed', $hash);
    $hash = hash('sha512', $password);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['admin_local']=$row['ID_Admin'];
        echo''.$_SESSION['admin_local'].'';
    } else {
        echo 'error_msg';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, questions like "please tell me what's wrong with my code" are offtopic on this site. You have to learn to program first.

Comment: I think you misunderstood `SHA512` encrypted password only on checking time

Comment: I dont get why you're so harsh your common sense. That error_msg is not supposed to recive error msg from sql, it's for ajax data return.My question was why it doesnt set the session since username and password are the same with database values

Answer (score 2):

The line below is always false and assigns an empty line to the username and password. Change this line:

```
if ($password='' or $username='')
```

to

```
 if ($password=='' or $username=='')
```

Also, you should use something like [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for hashing your passwords.

Comment: The Op is allegedly getting "error_msg", not "mandatory", which makes this one rather a posting error. Either way the question is off topic.

Comment: He enters correct username and password. After `if` , they are zero-length strings. When he executes the statement, `fetch` will return `FALSE` and `error_msg` will be printed.

Comment: My bad, indeed this is the case.